# You need access to the source report type to view this report chart

Tags: custom-report-type, experience-cloud

I have a community site with a report chart. the report chart is not visible due to the error in the title but a dashboard containing the same report is visible(see screenshot below). What permissions do I need to enable so the standalone report chart is visible?
[image]

Please note that the dashboard running user is the system admin. I want to remove the dashboard and leave the report chart but need to identify what report type access to enable.

Comment: Can you check the report fields are accessible by the respective user or not?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail.  Does the dashboard have a running user that is different from the error user?  Please [edit] your post.

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi yes, confirmed that all report objects and fields are accessible to the site user through permission set

Comment: @DavidCheng yes, dashboard has a different running user will edit post to reflect this

Comment: If this is a custom report type, make sure it is in Deployed status.  Otherwise, the basic area to check is object permissions for the community user profile / permission sets.